# How to create base authentication in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create base authentication in kubernetes. every document say that I should create CSV or file then enter the username and password in it. but I do not want to use file I want to some database or kubernetes handle it.
what can I do for base authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can based your authentication on tokens if you don't want to use static pasword file.

**First option:**

**Service Account Tokens**

A service account is an automatically enabled authenticator that uses signed bearer tokens to verify requests. 
The plugin uses two flags(which are optional):

Service accounts are usually created automatically by the API server and associated with pods running in the cluster through the ServiceAccount Admission Controller. Bearer tokens are mounted into pods at well-known locations, and allow in-cluster processes to talk to the API server. Accounts may be explicitly associated with pods using the serviceAccountName field of a **PodSpec**.

Service account bearer tokens are perfectly valid to use outside the cluster and can be used to create identities for long standing jobs that wish to talk to the Kubernetes API. To manually create a service account, simply use the kubectl create serviceaccount (NAME) command. This creates a service account in the current namespace and an associated secret.

The created secret holds the public CA of the API server and a signed JSON Web Token (JWT).

The signed **JWT** can be used as a bearer token to authenticate as the given service account. See above for how the token is included in a request. Normally these secrets are mounted into pods for in-cluster access to the API server, but can be used from outside the cluster as well.

There is some drawbacks because service account tokens are stored in secrets, any user with read access to those secrets can authenticate as the service account. Be careful when granting permissions to service accounts and read capabilities for secrets.

**Second:**

Install **OpenID Connect** (full documentation you can find here: [`oidc`](https://openid.net/connect/)).

OpenID Connect (OIDC) is a superset of OAuth2 supported by some service providers, notably Azure Active Directory, Salesforce, and Google. The protocol’s main addition on top of OAuth2 is a field returned with the access token called an ID Token. This token is a **JSON Web Token (JWT)** with well known fields, such as a user’s email, signed by the server.

To identify the user, the authenticator uses the **id_token** (not the access_token) from the OAuth2 token response as a bearer token.

Since all of the data needed to validate who you are is in the **id_token**, Kubernetes doesn’t need to “phone home” to the identity provider. In a model where every request is stateless this provides a very scalable solution for authentication.

Kubernetes has **no** “web interface” to trigger the authentication process. There is no browser or interface to collect credentials which is why you need to authenticate to your identity provider first.
There’s no easy way to authenticate to the Kubernetes dashboard without using the kubectl proxy command or a reverse proxy that injects the **id_token**.

More information you can find here: [`kubernetes-authentication`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).